# Good way to send 200k mails per day with c#

Tags: c#-4.0, architecture, smtp

I work at Across an Human Resource company and we are building a new system for our young professionals department. That application needs to send a lot of mail in different cenarious (update resume, lost password, events, tests, etc.) for all registered users and I have a architecture issue/question.

That system will send several groups of e-mail in a day, each group probably will have around 30k and we believe that the system will send more than 10 groups per day.

My first idea was to create a Windows Service to process all email groups in my e-mail table (SQL), but I will have problems with availability and one single point of failure.

I'm just concerning about that because my queue will take hours to send all groups (each mail individually in a row).

Anybody knows how big systems like twitter / facebook /instragram and so on sends that amount of mail? I'm concerned about infrastructure and development.

Btw, i'm using smtpClient.Send() and I'm not into using smtpClient.SendAsync() because I have trouble to maintaing and control it.

I'm open to any sugestions from the Infrastructure to the dev side. All the infrastructure will relies on AWS Datacenter (SES) or Microsoft Azure, our infra team is testing both of them.

Comment: A basic calculation shows that it's a very little load. 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds = 86 400. 200 000 / 86 400 = 2.3 messages per second. It doesn't matter how poorly you design that application. It should still be able to handle that. 
Just make sure that your SMTP server can handle it (which probably most servers can).

Comment: This might not be a very helpful suggestion, but sharing it.. Have you evaluated 3rd Party Apps like SendGrid [1]?

[1] http://sendgrid.com/

Answer (score 0):

This works for us to send out our batch email:

```
public void sendEmail(String email, PdfDocument attachFile)
    {
        attachFile.Save("attachment.pdf");
        attachFile.Close();
        SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.domain.com", 25);
        mSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        mSmtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("address@domain.com", String.Empty, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(email.ToString());
        MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage(from, to);
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment at = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("Payroll Direct Deposit Notification.pdf");
        mMailMessage.Body = "Please see attached for your pay summary.";
        mMailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mMailMessage.Subject = "subject";
        mMailMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(at);
        try
        {
            mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        at.Dispose();
        attachFile.Dispose();
    }
```

You may want to adjust the mSmtpClient.Timeout from the default depending on what the hardware you are relaying off of is capable of,  you can use separate threads that call this function or send asynchronously depending on how you build the rest of your applications, or you can just jack up the timeout to smooth it out if that's your preference.